Adjust list settings dynamically according to widest label in current page
I have a use case where I'd like adjust the list settings for each page according to the widest item label in that page. The case at hand involves "enumerate like" very long lists reaching the hundreds of items across several pages. Let's say I'm trying for a list with hanging indent, which I'd like to align with the label plus a constant width. The trouble here is that, for a list with labels from 1 to 3 digits, whatever fixed hang I set will look bad at either the beginning or the end of the list.
This is thus different from a more common requirement of using the "widest label in the whole list", for example at Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?. Because I'd like to adjust settings along a single list, at each page.
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\mylabelwidthcurrpage}
\setlength{\mylabelwidthcurrpage}{1em}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylisthang}{}
  {\list{}{
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\mylabelwidthcurrpage}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\mylabelwidthcurrpage}
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-2\leftmargin}
      \let\makelabel\mylistmakelabel
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}
      \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\topsep}{.5\topsep}
      \setlength{\partopsep}{.5\partopsep}
    }
  }
  {\endlist}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylistmakelabel}{m}
  {\hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont #1}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \mydonitems } { m }
  { \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { \item[##1] \lipsum[1-2] } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisthang}
  \mydonitems{200}
\end{mylisthang}

\end{document}

Now, assume that I could set, after each shipout the value of \mylabelwidthcurrpage to contain the widest label for the next page (not shown here...). Would the list behave as I'd expect? The question here is if this kind of thing is possible at all. Take the page from the MWE above at the page we reach a three digit label:

My main concern here is about that rest of item 99 and whether it would adjust to the new value of \mylabelwidthcurrpage or if it would have already been typeset during the previous shipout. But I assume still other problems might arise...
Can this work at all?
Edit: Given @yannisl comment, perhaps a little more context would be useful. The concrete use case here is an endnotes package (postnotes). And list design (or paragraph design if you don't use lists) is "tricky"/"stiff" for endnotes in general because of this "increasing label width" effect. Things which would look just fine in shorter lists become problematic because of it. This is not about this particular list design (hanging indent), but on how to get more design flexibility in general for the use case. After all, there's really no need to maintain an alignment consistent "10 pages later", but we'd be happy to do so for each page.
I already have the information of which note starts at which (abs) page, I could just as well revert it and get the list of notes occurring in a given page and measure their widths. So I could in principle provide some \mylabelwidthcurrpage and update it every shipout. The question is really whether it is technically feasible to adjust LaTeX list parameters mid-list "on-the-fly" with one such variable.
Edit 2: Here is a MWE which does not do what I'd hope it to do, but is more "playable", in that it provides (in contrived form) a variable (that is, not fixed) \mylabelwidthcurrpage:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylisthang}{}
  {\list{}{
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\mylabelwidthcurrpage}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\mylabelwidthcurrpage}
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-2\leftmargin}
      \let\makelabel\mylistmakelabel
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}
      \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\topsep}{.5\topsep}
      \setlength{\partopsep}{.5\partopsep}
    }
  }
  {\endlist}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylistmakelabel}{m}
  {\hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont #1}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \mylabelwidthcurrpage
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {0}
\dim_gset:Nn \mylabelwidthcurrpage { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + \labelsep }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mydonitems } { m }
  { \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { \item[##1] \lipsum[1-2] } }
\AddToHook{shipout/after}
  {
    \int_case:nn { \int_use:c {c@page} }
      {
        {3}
        {
          \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {00}
          \dim_gset:Nn \mylabelwidthcurrpage
            { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + \labelsep }
        }
        {43}
        {
          \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {000}
          \dim_gset:Nn \mylabelwidthcurrpage
            { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + \labelsep }
        }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisthang}
  \mydonitems{200}
\end{mylisthang}

\end{document}


Is an interesting problem, but personally I would just put the label in the margin. It will be easier to see it as well. Be also aware that currently lists are redefined as part of the tagging project to use templates.

@yannisl That's a possibility too. The context here is that this is for an endnotes package. The list environment is a user option, so I take it as "arbitrary". And I take this is an effect users might want to achieve. I'm confident that I could provide such a variable and update it every shipout. But I'm unsure if it would be meaningful to do so. Thus the question.

I'm not sure it's practical to apply different list parameters to different parts of the same paragraph. besides this, what should happen if 99 starts on an even page and ends on an odd odd one in a double-sided document? should the pattern still change at the page break? is this a common format? it seems to me usually numbers are either in the margin or inline. the hanging layout seems a bit odd, to be honest. (or maybe I can imagine something like this in legal documents, possibly?)

@cfr As I said in the edit, it is not about this particular layout, but whether it is feasible to change the parameters mid-list. And, maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think lists do anything different in case of double-sided documents.

@gusbrs I didn't mean they did something different, but only that it isn't clear to me how you would mean this to look for a double-page spread.

@cfr Oh, well, I can say then that, for the purposes of the problem at hand, I don't expect odd and even pages to be treated differently. ;-) That's not what I'm worried about.

OK, suppose that the widest entry in the current page is “aaa”, but at some stage of the process, the space reserved is that for “aaaaaa” (say from the preceding page). Now you reprocess and more words fit on the page, moving at the end of it an entry with “aaaaaa”. Oops!

@egreg Indeed, wipet has shown neatly this is a convergence problem. To worsen things, naturally, we don't have the page numbers on the first run, since they come from pagerefs, as they must, so we have to begin with some arbitrary starting value. True that for the use case at hand the widths would not normally swing that much but, yeah, technically the marks can be arbitrarily set by the user.

It seems like very interesting problem. I tried to implement a prototype in OpTeX (no in LaTeX). You can experiment with this, inspire from this and maybe, re-implement it to a TeX format you are using. But the prototype shows, that there is unexpected problem which makes it impossible to solve it in general terms.
You can try the following code. Run it with optex many times until the warning "Try to rerun, test.ref file was changed." is printed on the terminal (six times with this example).
\fontfam[lm]

\refdecl{  %% scanning ref file
\newcount\itxnum
\def\currpagenum{\ea\ignoresecond\_currpage}
\def\Xiwidth#1{
   \ifcsname iwd:\currpagenum\endcsname
       \ifdim\cs{iwd:\currpagenum}<#1 \sxdef{iwd:\currpagenum}{#1}\fi
   \else
       \sxdef{iwd:\currpagenum}{#1}
   \fi
   \incr\itxnum
   \sxdef{itx:\the\itxnum}{\currpagenum}
   \sxdef{iln:\the\itxnum}{}
}
\def\Xitxline{\sxdef{iln:\the\itxnum}{\cs{iln:\the\itxnum}{\currpagenum}}}
} % end of \refdecl

\ifx\itxnum\undefined \newcount\itxnum \fi
\itxnum=0

\def\itx #1{%  item macro, #1 is its label
   \incr\itxnum           %% number of the item
   \setbox0=\hbox{\bf#1 } %% label in bold will be measured
   \setbox1=\vbox\bgroup
      \ifcsname itx:\the\itxnum \endcsname
         \leftskip=\cs{iwd:\cs{itx:\the\itxnum}}  % \leftskip = max width of the page
      \else \leftskip=\wd0 \fi  % no .ref data, \leftskip = \wd0 only
      \ifcsname iln:\the\itxnum\endcsname %% preparing \parshape data
         \def\psdata{} \edef\tmpa{\cs{itx:\the\itxnum}} \def\tmpb{0pt\hsize} \tmpnum=0
         \ea\ea\ea \foreach \csname iln:\the\itxnum\endcsname \do
            {\incr\tmpnum 
                \ifnum##1>\tmpa \def\tmpa{##1}\itxdifflines \fi 
             \edef\psdata{\psdata\tmpb}}
         \parshape \tmpnum \psdata \relax  %% setting \parshape
      \fi
      \noindent 
      \openref \_ewref \Xiwidth{{\the\wd0}}% writing label width to .ref 
      \llap{\hss\box0}\ignorespaces
}
\def\enditx{\par    % decomposing the lines if the item 
   \setbox2=\hbox{}
   \loop
      \setbox0=\lastbox
      \ifvoid0 \else             %% adding \write\Xitxline to each line
      \global\setbox2=\hbox{\box0 \_wref\Xitxline{}\penalty0\unhbox2}
      \unskip\unskip\unpenalty
      \repeat
   \egroup
   {\leftskip=-.9\hsize plus1fill \noindent \unhbox2 \par}
} 
\def\itxdifflines{
   \edef\tmp{\dimexpr\cs{iwd:\tmpa}-\cs{iwd:\cs{itx:\the\itxnum}}}
   \edef\tmpb{\tmp\dimexpr\hsize-\tmp}
}

% Test:

\itx {dfda chkav fhadk} \lorem[1] \enditx
\itx {dfda} \lorem[2] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fhadk fhjks} \lorem[3] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav f} \lorem[4] \enditx
\itx {df} \lorem[5] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fh} \lorem[6] \enditx
\itx {dfda chfhadk} \lorem[7] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fh} \lorem[7] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fh} \lorem[8] \enditx
\itx {df} \lorem[9] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fha} \lorem[10] \enditx
\itx {dfda ch} \lorem[11] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fh} \lorem[12] \enditx
\itx {dfda chk} \lorem[1] \enditx
\itx {dfda} \lorem[2] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fhadk fhjks} \lorem[3] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav f} \lorem[4] \enditx
\itx {df} \lorem[5] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fh} \lorem[6] \enditx
\itx {dfda chfhadk} \lorem[7] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav fhadk fg} \lorem[7] \enditx
\itx {dfda chkav} \lorem[8] \enditx
\itx {df} \lorem[9] \enditx
\itx {dfda ch ryuw} \lorem[10] \enditx
\itx {dfda ch tier yur yuw } \lorem[11] \enditx
\itx {dfda chk dhj} \lorem[12] \enditx

\bye

How it works
First TeX run macros print to the .ref file the natural widths of each item label. So, we know the page number where starts each item. Moreover, the paragraph of each item is decomposed to the lines and the \write\refffile{\Xitxline} is appended to each line. So, we can see the number of lines of each item and the point where the lines go to next page (if it is true). The .ref file looks like this:
...
\Xiwidth{68.66998pt}
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xiwidth{71.85999pt}
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\_Xpage{2}{2}
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xiwidth{58.12999pt}
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xitxline
\Xiwidth{13.73pt}
...

Note that the item with width of its label 71.85999pt has three lines on page 1 and next 5 lines on page two. When we read such .ref file, we can calculate the widest label on each page and we can prepare \parshape data for the situation where lines form a single item go to next page. Of course, we create a new .ref file in this second run. OpTeX checks if the .ref file from previous TeX run to the current TeX run was changed. If it is true, OpTeX prints warring.
Where is the problem
The problem is that the individual TeX runs converge slowly to the desired result and, moreover, it may happen that the process never converges. The probability of such case is very high. The process is very unstable. You can try to change the label widths in my example and do more experiments.

Very interesting, and trickier than the tricky I already thought this would be. ;-) I admit I'm completely unfamiliar with OpTeX and (probably not only for this reason) that I have a hard time following the details of the code. But I hope to have gotten the general idea of what you are trying to demonstrate. You are working line by line to be able to solve the issue of the "lines remaining from the last item of the previous page". And also get that this needs to be a convergence problem, which is not ensured. [...].

[...] True, for the use envisaged use case, the label widths would not swing so wildly, but I agree the logical problem remains... Thank you very much!

Playing here, for "well behaved" labels (a sequence of numbers, which is what I'd expect for the use case), I get convergence in two runs, which is the fastest possible since the .ref file has to be written in the first. But, yeah, the general problem is hard...
